# How to deal with anonymous functions in javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I need to store an anonymous function passed as argument of my "named" function in Javascript, and then call it later.

How can I do this? I already know how to pass an anonymous function as an argument, but I don't know how to deal with it when I'm "on the other side" of the code.

Thank you

Comment: just store it in any relative to the fuction/context. like `function xxx(f){ this.handler=f; }` //change this to some other object, self, whatever. later you can just call it w/ `this.handler()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Functions in JavaScript](http://helephant.com/2008/08/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/) are [first-class members](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/First-class_function) which means that you can work with them just as you would any other data type in the language - you can pass them as arguments, keep them as member variables inside of other functions, return them from functions etc.

In the case you've asked about, it works just like any other named variable with the neat addition that you can invoke the function as below since it *is* a function:

```
function myFunc(anonymous){
    var arg1;
    anonymous(arg1);
}

myFunc(function(arg1){console.log(arg1)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call it using the name of the parameter.

```
function callThisLater(laterFunction) {
  // ...
  laterFunction(args);
}

callThisLater(function (arg1) {
    alert("We've been called!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is basic example:

```
function Foo(func) {
    this.Func = func;
    this.Activate = function() {
        this.Func();
    };
}

var foo = new Foo(function() { alert("activated"); });
foo.Activate();
```

I believe that what you missed is using the `()` to "activate" the function - as far as I understand you reached the point of  "storing" the function to variable.

Answer (score 0):

can you assign your anonymous function passed as an argument to a named function to a global variable inside the named function and then can used the global variable as a reference to anonymous function.

Comment: So you're *not* talking about **global** variables then, since it's a variable *inside* a function. That should probably be edited so it's not confusing.